# Any good Linear Algebra textbook that gives a good geometrical intuition?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I want a book that maybe has pictures in it or just the author trying to explain what things mean geometrically.

Comment: *Linear and Geometric Algebra* by Alan Macdonald.  Note that it does take a different approach than your going to see in class (almost certainly) so you'll have to do a little mental conversion to translate your professor's lectures and your homework into the ideas from Macdonald's book.

Comment: @Bye_World but will i be able to keep up with it due to its different approach? I am an amateur really.

Comment: The central ideas of linear algebra are constant.  Macdonald just emphasizes geometrical ideas (like multivectors) and linear transformations where most linear algebra classes emphasize matrices.  The unlying ideas are the same, but the form those ideas take can differ.  It couldn't hurt to have a different perspective on the topics than your classmates.

Comment: But for a (somewhat) more traditional textbook you could try *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler.  It requires maybe a bit more mathematical "maturity" though.

Comment: Or if you read Russian, По́стников's books are really good. ;)  If you do want to take a look at his book series start with the first one on analytic geometry rather than the second on linear algebra -- he introduces a lot of linear algebraic ideas in that first volume and occasionally makes reference to affine and projective space in the second.

Comment: @Bye_World Sadly, i do not speak Russian, but thanks for the recommendations! I will surely check out the books. Do you know if Strang's books are as good as these?

Comment: I haven't read Strang's books so I couldn't tell you how geometrical they are.  But I've seen a lot of people recommend them here in the past.